# How to reliably iterate over the fields of an Array?

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, indexing, iteration

I have this awk script:

```
!/NaN/{
    nodes=$1;
    range=$2;
    size=$3;
    frame=$4;
    arrRate=$5;
    type=$6;
    pl=$7;

    count[nodes,range,size,frame,arrRate,type,pl]++;
    sumth[nodes,range,size,frame,arrRate,type,pl]+=$11;
    sumdel[nodes,range,size,frame,arrRate,type,pl]+=$13;
    sumdeliv[nodes,range,size,frame,arrRate,type,pl]+=$15;
    sumthf[nodes,range,size,frame,arrRate,type,pl]+=$17;
    sumdelf[nodes,range,size,frame,arrRate,type,pl]+=$19;
    sumdelivf[nodes,range,size,frame,arrRate,type,pl]+=$21;
 }
 END{
    for (i in count) {
       split(i,sep,SUBSEP);
       for (x in sep) {
           printf "%s ", sep[x];
       }
       print sumth[i] / count[i],
             sumdel[i] / count[i],
             sumdeliv[i] / count[i],
             sumthf[i] / count[i],
             sumdelf[i] / count[i],
             sumdelivf[i] / count[i],
             count[i]
    }
 }
```

When I run it on `mawk 1.3.3` I get output like:

```
100 10 100 10 0.0001778279 DRAND 0.0 ...
```

but when I run in on `GNU Awk 3.1.5`, I get:

```
10 0.0001778279 DRAND 0.7 100 10 100 ...
```

or the first columns are printed in different order.

Is there any reliable way to iterate over the indexes of an `awk` array, in a way that gives consistent output, regardless of the awk version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just replace the code block:

```
 split(i,sep,SUBSEP);
 for (x in sep) {
   printf "%s ", sep[x];
  }
```

with

```
printf "%s ",i
```

the `(x in array)` won't grantee the order, if you have to split and print them, you could:

```
n=split(i,sep,SUBSEP);
 for (x=1;x<=n;x++) {
   printf "%s ", sep[x];
  }
```

Comment: Yes this worked. Thank you. I wonder where someone could find the documentation regarding the order...

Comment: For the record, the `printf "%s", i` prints a `^\\` character between the fields, but the last block works perfectly.

Comment: @user000001 http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array `The order in which elements of the array are accessed by this statement is determined by the internal arrangement of the array elements within awk and normally cannot be controlled or changed.` also the 1st paragraph of the following section

Comment: @user000001 `By default, when a for loop traverses an array, the order is undefined, meaning that the awk implementation determines the order in which the array is traversed. This order is usually based on the internal implementation of arrays and will vary from one version of awk to the next.`

Comment: @ kent: Thank you for the link. `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` looks interesting.